# Floating action button not visible over the Google Map in Android Studio

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, autocomplete, floating-action-button

My screen has a AutoComplete Google Search at the top, Google Maps below and a floating action button at the bottom end.

When I try to add a floating action button over Google Maps at the bottom end, the button is not visible on the screen.

This is my activity_maps.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">


    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="55dp" 
        />



    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        />

   <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="35dp">
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="112dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"/>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How much xml files do you have?

Comment: Just this one file.

Comment: So your java file inflate this one?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

    />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```